# How to make an automated task, less detectable by randomising the interval (within bounds)

Tags: python, random, scheduling

How would I go about making this run from 250 - 350 second loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the random() package. Read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html).

Modifying the original function:

```
import random
random.seed()

def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
    event_time = start
    while event_time < end:
        s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
        event_time += interval + random.random(-60, 60)
    s.run()
```

Once upon a time when I was definitely not writing a script to make (fake) money on a web-based game, I used a mixture of [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), and python's random() with a gaussian distribution to log myself on and take care of things. Good times.

Comment: First of all, lol brilliant! Secondly I havnt started using the start and end times in the run periodically code, when setting a start time, how do you format the time? One other question, the for loop there `while event_time < end:` what if you wanted to schedule the start time as 22:30 in the evening and the end time as 21:30 the following day? Would that render said loop broken? Kind regards AEA

Comment: The scheduler class is maybe a little more complicated than you need to deal with right now (it's not that bad, just particular). Try using time.sleep() instead to familiarize yourself with timekeeping in code.

Comment: Should i have asked said question in a new thread? I'm not entirely sure of the rules.

Comment: Hi whilst trying to run the code in the way you supplied It didnt work,: 'module' object is not callable. I then supposed that `+ random` should actually by `+random.seed` to which i got the error .seed can take 2 arguments, and apparently I have provided 3. :s

Comment: Hey dan appreciate the advice, but I learn much better by manipulating code, from examples.I do read up on functions all the time, but sometimes its hard to know where to start.

Comment: I ran the code import random
random.seed()

`import datetime
from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep

######Code to loop the script and set up scheduling time

s = scheduler(time, sleep)



def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
    event_time = start
    while event_time < end:
        s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
        event_time += interval + random.random(-5, 45)
    s.run()` I get the call back, `random() takes no arguments (2 given)`

Comment: For anyone who accidentally stumbles across this thread the answer to my woes was the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930228/use-of-the-random-function-to-randomise-scheduled-tasks