# Use of the random function to randomise scheduled tasks

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I am trying to use the code:

```
import random
import datetime
from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep

s = scheduler(time, sleep)
random.seed()

def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
    event_time = start
    while event_time < end:
        s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
        event_time += interval + random.random(-5, 45)
    s.run()

getData()#######

run_periodically(time()+5, time()+1000000, 10, getData)
```

I am trying to get the scheduled time and or the scheduled interval to have some degree of randomisation, currently the code returns the

```
typeError: random() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

If anyone could either tell me how to fix this or provide an alternative method it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `help(random.random)` in the terminal (or `random.random??` if you're using iPython) and you'll get:

`random() -> x in the interval [0, 1).`

So it doesn't take any input which is the reason behind the error. To generate a random number within a certain range you can use `random.randint` (which is linked to `random.randrange`).

So it would be like this for your case: `random.randint(-5,45)`

Answer (score 1):

random.random is not the function you want.  You want to use `random.randrange` or `random.randint` depending on your version.

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html for more details.

Comment: random.random is a valid function: http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random It returns a random float between 0 and 1.0